# Jquery if condition on mouse leave or mouse enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Hello People here is my jquery code.

```
$(val1+","+val2).mouseleave(function(){

    $('.opacity').remove();
    $(val3).show();
    $(val4).hide();

});
```

i want to edit this code in such a way that after

```
$(val1+","+val2).mouseleave(function(){
    if mouse doe not  enter val3 or val4
then 
    $('.opacity').remove();
$(val3).show();
$(val4).hide();
else
    nothing....
```

something like ...

```
$(val1 + "," + val2).mouseleave(function() {

    if ($(val3 + "," + val4).mouseenter) {
    } else {
        $('.opacity').remove();
        $(val3).show();
        $(val4).hide();
    }

});
```

obviously above does not work ... iam wrong somewhere near if condition how to fix this?

Comment: it would also help if you show/explain how val1-4 are located with respect to each other.
From what I see - I can say that you can add "mouseenter" handler to val3/4 and add "opacity" in it.

Comment: I think you don't need the if else statement inside the block. Just $().mouseenter would probably do the trick because I believe that's where the event binding is being done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should play with a variable updated according to the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` information about `val3` and `val4`

```
var isHoverSpecialDiv = false;

$(val3 + "," + val4).hover(
    function(){
        isHoverSpecialDiv = true;
    },
    function(){
        isHoverSpecialDiv = false;
    }
});
```

And test it

```
$(val1 + "," + val2).mouseleave(function() {

    //Test condition
    if (isHoverSpecialDiv == false) 
    {
        $('.opacity').remove();
        $(val3).show();
        $(val4).hide();
    }
});
```