# Jquery condition for if does not mouseenters

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets take an example i have `4 divs` div1,div2,div3,div4 all four divs are separted from each other,Now i want to write a condition in jquery ,

1)`if mouseleaves div1' and`if it does not enter into div3 or div4` ,then i want run a function or alert what ever...

currently iam doing this by checking `if mouseenters div3 or div4` .
something like this...

but i actually want to do in a reverse ways.... is it possible to achieve this?

```
$(".div11").mouseleave(function(){

if ( $(".div3,.div4").mouseenter)(function(){

 });

else{}

});
```

As u know above code does not work because i messed up if else condition ,, but iam trying to write something similar...

Comment: That syntax doesn't look right....

Comment: Post your HTML. Also do you want something specific to happen if the user hovers div1 before the others?

Comment: ya as i have mentioned , i know that syntax is wrong,so iam want to know the correct syntax for if else condtion in jquery...why downvote?

Comment: `if else` syntax in jquery is just like `if else` syntax in any other programming language. in addition, the eventhandler syntax is wrong.

Comment: Isn't this the same as [your own question a couple of days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378599/jquery-if-condition-on-mouse-leave-or-mouse-enter)? And [your other question yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424352/check-variable-true-with-if-statement)? I notice you're still trying to bind a mouseenter handler from inside your mouseleave handler even though I told you yesterday that that wouldn't work.

Comment: yes @nnnnnn but this time iam trying in different way....

Comment: If what you are trying to do is create a menu, check the internet first. There are a lot of implementations out there...

Comment: But you're _not_ trying in a different way. It's basically a minor variation on the same thing. It makes no sense to try to call a mouseenter function inside an `if` condition. Somebody else gave you a reasonable solution yesterday.

Comment: no @nnnnnn that did not work , because iam running this code within loop..

Comment: There's no loop shown in your question - were we supposed to guess that part? Why do you think the loop matters? Again, as I told you yesterday, you need to edit the question to provide a reasonably detailed explanation of what you are trying to achieve, why you have a loop, etc.

Comment: iam sorry for not specifying that @nnnnnn ,i thought loop issues i can manage after resolving this ... well now iam able to  resolve this issue by the modifying the solution given by user2110309.. anyways i really appreciate your patience and your interest in solving this ..thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this would be the correct syntax:

```
$(".div1").mouseleave(function () {

//Check if mouse is over div3 or div4
if ($('.div3').is(':hover') || $('.div4').is(':hover')) {
  //Do something    
    } 
else {

    }    
  });
```

Do you agree?

Comment: thanks for your solution @user2110309,let me implement ur code....

Comment: now your code works as i wish ....:) thanks alot for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Yes. Provided out of the box? No. You would probably have to implement this yourself.

For that, think about the [DOM EVent Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event). In order to implement "not mouse enter", you would have to write a custom event that triggers on every mouse movement. It would check for the position of the cursor relative to the borders of the target element, see if it's "within" the element's boundaries (do you include margin? padding?), and if not then call the passed in event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You should use variables when enter in another divs...

for example:

```
var div3enter = false;
var div4enter = false;
$('.div3').mouseenter(function(){ div3enter = true; });
$('.div4').mouseenter(function(){ div4enter = true; });

$(".div11").mouseleave(function(){

if(div3enter and div4enter) {
//do something....
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timeout based solution

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var timer;
    $(".div1").mouseleave(function() {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            alert('delayed');
        }, 100);
    });

    $(".div3,.div4").mouseenter(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer)
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RCHJN/)